# Implement JSON Array Input in POST method Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have `POST` method API that have a `request body` of JSON array like:

```
[{
    "bookID":123,
    "userID": 1,
    "isLike": true
},
{
    "bookID":143,
    "userID": 2,
    "isLike": false
}]
```

and my `inputs` in my `controller` is like:

```
inputs: {
 bookID: {
   required: true,
   type: 'number'
 },
 userID: {
   required: true,
   type: 'number'
 },
 isLike: {
   type: 'boolean'
   defaultsTo: false,
 }
```

}

My problem is how can I access the `inputs` in the

```
fn: async function (inputs) {}
```

I tried changing the `inputs` to `[inputs]` but it won't work.

Comment: If you pass the ```inputs``` in the function, you can access it. What is your actual question?

Comment: I see. Before you pass your JSON, yoou can use ```JSON.parse(inputs)``` to make it a JS object.